# Why does my app require the full .NET 4 Framework?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, .net-client-profile

I have a WinForms app targeting the .NET 4 Client Profile. However, when I try to run it on a machine that has only the Client Profile (and not the full/extended profile), I get ".NET Framework Initialization Error" saying I need to install ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0":

[image: ".NET Framework Initialization Error" saying I need to install ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"]

I've double-checked the project file to make sure that it is indeed targeting the client profile, and it is:

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
<TargetFrameworkProfile>Client</TargetFrameworkProfile>
```

As are all of the projects it references. I'm not even sure where else to look - what is going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your app.configs and verify the supported runtime specified in the startup:

```
<startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />
</startup>
```

should be replaced with

```
<startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client" />
</startup>
```